# Размер buffer`а

Tags: c++

Использую следующий код:

```
int mret;
char buffer[2048];
string response;

mret = recv(s, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
response = string(buffer);
fill_n(buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL);
```

При этом все объявления делаю за пределами функции. Однако, если перенести их внутрь функции (что мне сейчас и нужно), то происходит не приятная ситуация:
`responce` вместо того, что бы подстроить свой `size` автоматически, равным размерам текста из `buffer` (допустим 200), ставит `size` равным 20**5**8, заполняя остальное пространство знаками вопроса `?`.

Почему это произошло и как этого избежать? Объявление обязательно должно быть внутри функции.

Comment: `fill_n(buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL);` - что здесь делает `NULL`?

Comment: @AnT тихо поживает. А что с ним не так?

Comment: `NULL` предназначен для использования в указательных контекстах. А вы его в `char` запихивать пытаетесь. Какой смысл запихивать **null pointer constant** в `char`? В современном С++ макро `NULL` может быть определено как `nullptr`. Что тогда будет с вашим `fill_n`? Лучше уж напишите `fill_n(buffer, sizeof(buffer), false);`. Это `false` там тоже странно выглядеть будет, но это намного логичнее, чем ваш `NULL`.

Comment: @AnT окей, как скажете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если `string` является `::std::string`, то конструктор будет принимать на вход оканчивающуюся нулем строку, а вы ей передаете буфер потенциально полностью забитый мусором. Инициализация вне функции видимо работает так как глобальные переменные всегда инициализируются нулями. Соответственно перед присваиванием надо проверить результат вызова `recv` и поместить в строку именно полученное количество байт:

```
if((0 < mret) && (mret <= sizeof(buffer))
{
    response.assign(buffer, static_cast<size_t>(mret));
}
else
{
    // обработка ошибок...
}
```